# Animate inline-blocks to move over when new one comes in from left

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, css-animations

So I have a horizontal bar of items, and I want one to be hidden, and when hovering over the parent object, it slides into the left. I am trying different ways, such as using negative margins to hide the item until shown. However, there seems to be an issue of the item still being there but blank.
Ideally, I want no 'new' left item shown and all items to the left. Then, when the new one is shown, is slides in and all other items move over to let it in. This is with an unknown width of all items.

When not hovering:
[![not hovering][1]][1]

When hovering:
[![when hovering][2]][2]

Would anyone know how to best do this with tailwindcss? I am also using Vue.

````
    <div class="sticky top-2 bg-gray-100 p-1 rounded-full shadow-sm hover:shadow-md inline-block opacity-90 hover:opacity-100 group overflow-hidden" v-show="!hideMe">
      <ul class="relative">
      <template v-for="item in props.items" :key="item.id">
        <li class="inline-block">
          <template v-if="item.hidden">
            <button @click="scrollTo(item)"
            class="transition-all -ml-[100%] group-hover:ml-0 py-1 px-2 text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-400 rounded-full" >
              <component :is="item.icon" class="inline-block w-5 h-5 mr-1 -mt-0.5"/>
              <div class="inline-block">{{ item.name }}</div>
            </button>
          </template>
          <template v-else>
            <button @click="scrollTo(item)"
            class="py-1 px-2 text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-400 rounded-full" >
              <component :is="item.icon" class="inline w-5 h-5 mr-1 -mt-0.5"/>{{ item.name }}
            </button>
        </template>
      </li>
    </template>
  </ul>
    </div>
</template>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjXLl.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJJNX.png
````

Answer (score 0):

We can use Vue's transition and Tailwind's utility classes.
Tailwind does not do animation directly so we have to make a build something. You can either extend Tailwind to include custom animations or use JavaScript to directly manipulate the DOM during transition hooks [Source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html?redirect=true).

Let's start by modifying the setting of Tailwind for theslide animations. in your `tailwind.config.js` file [Source](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-custom-animations-tailwind-css/):

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        slideIn: {
          '0%': { transform: 'translateX(-100%)' },
          '100%': { transform: 'translateX(0)' },
        },
        slideOut: {
          '0%': { transform: 'translateX(0)' },
          '100%': { transform: 'translateX(-100%)' },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        slideIn: 'slideIn 0.5s forwards',
        slideOut: 'slideOut 0.5s forwards',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

We define two keyframes: `slideIn` and `slideOut`. The `slideIn` keyframe will animate the element from being off-screen (translateX(-100%)) to its original position (translateX(0)). The `slideOut` will do the reverse.

In the your Vue component, let's use Vue transition component you can use the `v-show` directive to control the visibility of the item [Source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html?redirect=true).

```html
<transition name="slide" mode="out-in">
  <div v-show="show" class="animate-slideIn">
    <!-- Item content goes here -->
  </div>
</transition>
```

so the compenet will slide in when the `show` data property is true, and slide out when it's false.

Lastly when we need to make changes to  the `tailwind.config.js` we have to run  a build script (`npm run build` or `yarn build`).

Comment: thanks, but thats not the issue i am having. i have no trouble getting the animation working. The problem is when I have the (translateX(-100%)) there is still a blank space where the object was.

Comment: try this:
`<button 
  @click="scrollTo(item)"
  class="transition-all group-hover:translate-x-0 group-hover:opacity-100 group-hover:visible invisible opacity-0 -translate-x-full py-1 px-2 text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-400 rounded-full" >
  <component :is="item.icon" class="inline-block w-5 h-5 mr-1 -mt-0.5"/>
  <div class="inline-block">{{ item.name }}</div>
</button>` the button will not disappear

Comment: thanks.
Unfortunately, it still leaves an empty space when the button is out to the left and hidden.

Comment: hi @PixelPaul, have ou checked the parent element? by default the parent will reserve the space fro the child even if it's hidden, you could use `flex` to adjust the `justify-content` property. something like `<div class="flex justify-start">` this should remove the empty space

Comment: that does help, but the problem then is the width. As the original width is unknown, so when I transition from w-0 ( when its hidden ). i don't know what to set the onhover width too.  As w-fit or w-auto or w-[100%] don't work.

Comment: @PixelPaul You can use max-width that is larger than the other width. When the element is shown, it will animate to its natural width like: `<button
 @click=""
 class="transition-all group-hover:translate-x-0 group-hover:opacity-100 group-hover:visible invisible opacity-0 -translate-x-full max-w-[1000px] py-1 px-2 text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-400 rounded-full"
>
 <component :is="item.icon" class="inline-block w-5 h-5 mr-1 -mt-0.5"/>
 <div class="inline-block">{{ item.name }}</div>
</>
` let me know if it does anything i have more solution we could try.